# R lme4 predictions

Tags: r, prediction, lme4

I have fitted a fairly straightforward three level model to my data.

```
 Model.3l <- lmer(diff ~ final.mark + max.mark + (1 | unit.code) + (1 | unit.code:item), data = seed.data)
```

I have then created a set of predictions using just the fixed effects from the model.

```
predicted <- predict(Model.3l, newdata=NULL, re.form=~0)
```

I have also extracted the parameter estimates and the random effects (code not included but cross checked). So here comes the naïve question.  Why do the predicted values from lme4 differ considerably from what I can calculate manually from the fixed effect parameter estimates using the following code?

```
predicted <- seed.data$fix.intercept + (seed.data$final.mark * seed.data$fix.final.mark) + (seed.data$max.mark * seed.data$fix.max.mark)
```

Here is some more detail as requested.  This is the summary of the model:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: diff ~ final.mark + max.mark + (1 | unit.code) + (1 | unit.code:item)
   Data: seed.data

REML criterion at convergence: 604847.5

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-20.6746  -0.3056   0.0119   0.2791  17.2782 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 unit.code:item (Intercept) 0.02895  0.17015 
 unit.code      (Intercept) 0.00790  0.08888 
 Residual                   0.45422  0.67396 
Number of obs: 294678, groups:  unit.code:item, 395; unit.code, 19

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  0.016734   0.027614    0.61
final.mark  -0.184453   0.001045 -176.59
max.mark     0.092059   0.003905   23.57

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
           (Intr) fnl.mr
final.mark -0.001       
max.mark   -0.557 -0.151
```

and here are a few lines of the data. Quite apart from anything I would expect the predictions for cases 7, 8, 9 and 12 to be the same.

```
   unit.code item final.mark max.mark diff fix.intercept fix.final.mark fix.max.mark re.intercept re.intercept.2   predicted
6          a    1          8       10    0    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126  0.20085239
7          a    1          7       10   -1    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126 -0.16805334
8          a    1          7       10   -1    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126  0.10845857
9          a    1          7       10    0    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126  0.01572996
10         a    1          4       10    0    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126 -0.16805334
11         a    1          6       10    0    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126  0.01639952
12         a    1          7       10   -1    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126 -0.07565952
13         a    1          6       10    0    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126  0.20085239
14         a    1          8       10   -2    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126  0.01606474
15         a    1          5       10    0    0.01673431     -0.1844529   0.09205904    -0.173901     0.01075126  0.56908855
```

Comment: Please show at least the output of `summary(Model.3l)` and `head(seed.data)`. It would be even better if you could create a reproducible example.

Comment: With which method was `seed.data$predicted`  calculated?

Comment: using the predict function in lme4.  I then used cbind to add it to the data frame.  I assume that the predicted values would be produced in the same order as the data frame.

Comment: Can you try `predict(Model.3l, newdata=seed.data, re.form=~0)`? Just to be sure. I believe you really need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I have done that and it works.  The problem was not with the predict function but with the cbind.  Thanks for your help